# Pointer difference between 2 int pointers

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
int main(void) {
    int *a;
    int *b = a++;
    printf("%d\n",b-a);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be 1 why is it -1?

Assume in the above question instead of `a++` I have `++a`.

Is it still undefined behavior?

Comment: What did you got ?

Comment: Because `b = a++` assigns `a` to `b` and then increments `a` (which doesn't affect `b`).

Comment: Hint: `printf("%d\n",b-a);`? Cm'on, you know the rest, :)

Comment: Difference between unrelated pointer invokes undefined behavior. Both should point to a the same array or one of them should point to one past that array.

Comment: @haccks What do you mean by unrelated pointers? Both are of same type int

Comment: The only undefined behaviour here is using an uninitialized `a`.

Comment: @haccks is right. pointer arithmetic only makes sense when both the pointers are pointing at the members of the same array. In this case it might be clear, but one cannot ignore the fact that this is undefined behaviour wrt the standard.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I didn't get your hint . Please explain

Comment: @Carl; C11-§6.5.6/8: *If both the pointer
operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
behavior is undefined*

Comment: telling someone their code has undefined behaviour when said undefined behaviour is trivial to correct and anyway doesn't  affect the actual problem the OP is asking about is pretty non-constructive. Thanks to @Cairnarvon for being helpful to OP.

Comment: The discussion at [Check if pointer points to given array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325787/check-if-pointer-points-to-given-array) may be useful.  Also, be aware that on some hardware (when it's a problem, it's usually on mainframe-like hardware that has complex pointer organizations), even reading an invalid (uninitialized) pointer — without dereferencing it — may lead to unexpected behaviour (core dumps, etc).

Comment: @CarlNorum, I think if the said undefined behaviour wasn't effecting the result, then the answer would have been `0`. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Haris-- No. If `a` were initialized, the statement `b = a++` assigns the value of `a` to `b`, and then increments the value of `a`. In this case, `b - a` is not `0`.

Comment: If `a` was initialized in the above code and ignoring the other undefined behaviour (its very hard for me to do that though), then `a - b` would have been `1`, and `b - a` would have been `-1`. Hmm, my bad.

Comment: @Haris-- I don't think that there is undefined behavior here if `a` is initialized and the format specifier in the `printf()` is fixed. Then `a` could safely be assigned to `b`, and it is perfectly legal to increment `a` by one, and also legal to then perform the subtraction `b - a`.

Answer (score 4):

**The First problem**, as I see here, is primarily with

```
 int *a;
```

`a` is automatic local, and the initial value is indeterminate (no explicit initialization), hence doing `a++` (or, `++a`, for the matter) invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**That said**, regarding the pointer subtraction, see this answer on [why we need the operands of subtraction operator to be address of elements from same array object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40631080/2173917).

**Finally**, the subtraction of two pointers produce the type `ptrdiff_t`, you should be using `%td` to print the result. Otherwise, you again invoke UB.

---

[*As mentioned in  below comments*]

Assuming the pointers are initialized properly, something like

```
int k[5] = {0};
int * a = &(k[0]);
int *b = a++;
printf("%td\n",b-a);
```

in that case, the result will be `-1`, as that is the *difference* in the index of both the elements (remember `a++` is [post-increment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators)).

Chapter §6.5.6/9, `C11` standard

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
>   or one past the last element of the array object; **the result is the difference of the
>   subscripts of the two array elements.**

Comment: I am *not* the down-voter. Just wanted to ask, why is `a++` UB here? AFAIK, here `a` is a pointer (and is already placed on the stack) and `a++` will increase the address stored in `a` by 4 or 8 or whatever. I think `(*a)++` would be UB. Please tell me what I am missing.

Comment: @babon are you confusing `a` with `&a`? `a++` is UB based on the same logic, if `a` would haven been an `int`, either.

Comment: And what would be the result, if the pointer were correctly initialized? OP is expecting 1...

Comment: @Bob__ It will be `-1`. for `a++` (b is _before_ increment), `++a` does not make much sense, both will be pointing to same element, anyway then.

Comment: Of course, and I think you should add that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Bob__ Not very sure if that's too much of _assumption_ from our side, but updated, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your code causes undefined behavior because it reads and modifies uninitialized variables.

Also the specifier %td should be used for printing pointer difference.

Let's assume the pointer a actually points to a valid object:

```
int i;
int *a = &i;
int *b = a++;
printf("%td\n",b-a);
```

The postfix `++` operator gives the current value of the operand and then increments the operand by one. The above code is identical to:

```
int i;
int *a = &i+1;
int *b = &i;
printf("%td\n",b-a);
```

Pointer a points to one-past the object i, and pointer b points to the object i. The subtraction will, due to pointer arithmetic, yield -1. If the operation was: `a-b` then the result would be 1.

This is defined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Difference of two pointers ((b-a) in this case) is not defined in C unless the two pointers are pointing to addresses of a same array.

Also, since the pointer 'a' in your code has not been assigned any address ( contains garbage value ), doing any kind of operation is a sin.

If you wish to see how does subtraction of two pointers work, then try to define an array and make these two pointers point to it.

Comment: `...are pointing to addresses of a same array` + `or one past the last element of the array`

Comment: And what would be the result, if the pointer were correctly initialized? OP is expecting 1...

Comment: @Bob__ Generally , we do (b-a) to get the number of elements of the array between these two pointers. but because of int *b = a++; the result will be -1, which is of no use

Answer (score 0):

When you increment the pointer, it does not add the value to 1. It just tells the pointer to point to the next location. Also, your pointers were never initialized and they are just pointing to random garbage numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`int *a` is a variable with automatic storage duration and never has its address taken (`&a`). The code therefore invokes undefined behavior (as per 6.3.2.1, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c/40674888#40674888)) and your program can't have any predictable outcome.

Using the `%d` format specifier on on a `ptrdiff_t` also invokes undefined behavior (7.21.6.1/9). You should use `%td` for `ptrdiff_t` and `%p` for pointers.

Thus you can't expect anything from your program. It can output anything, or nothing, or crash.

Answer (score -1):

That is **no** undefine behaviour

when you declared *a, a points to a memory location, `*b = a++`;  b to point to the same location as a, **AND** increaments a to point to a location 1 factor greater than the previous location that b points to.

`b - a = -1` //correct

i'll give example

```
int main(void)
     {
        int *a; // 0x408
        int *w = a++; // 0x400
        int *b = a++; // 0x404

        int c = (b-a);
        printf("%d\n",b-a);// -1
        printf("%d\n",w-a); // -2

        return 0;
    }
```

i intruduce **`w`** to better ilustrate

The run-time memory address of the variable will look similar to the ones above.

`b - a` ( 0x404 - 0x408) == -1( -4 );

the sizeof int( in this case ) is 4 bytes. and pointers holding the address of int will have their address changing(+/-) by factor of 4,
as far is int is concern in this case 4 bytes hold one integer(1 unit)

`w - a == (0x400 - 0x408) = -2( -8 )`

if you had

`a - w == (0x408 - 0x400) = 2( 8 )`